# How to sort alphabetize a concatenated column

Tags: sorting, powerbi

I would like to sort alphabetize a column that is concatenated with another, that is, I am creating a custom column in which I am concatenating two columns.

The custom column formula I am using is the following:

```
= [IdCliente] & " - " & [NombreCliente]
```

The column I'm interested in alphabetizing is `[NombreCliente]`

Try to sort the column by `[NombreCliente]` making use of the function `Order.Ascending` as follows:

```
= [IdCliente] & " - " & Order.Ascending [NombreCliente]
```

But this is generated by an error indicating the following:

```
Expression.Error: Cannot apply field access to type Number.
Details:
    Value=0
    Key=NombreCliente
```

Any suggestion to correctly sort my column alphabetically.

**UPDATE 1:**

This is an example of how you would like the ordered data to look

It is important to bear in mind that the value A0002 comes from the column `[IdCliente]` and the CEST value comes from the column `[NombreCliente]`

```
|Not Order      |Order
|-----------------------------      
|A0002 - CEST   |A0012 - ARCET
|-----------------------------
|A0012 - ARCET  |A0002 - CEST
|-----------------------------
|A0015 - FULL   |A0015 - FULL
```

**UPDATE 2:**

I have arranged alphabetically the column `[NombreCliente]` in Power Query but when transferring it to a table the same order is maintained taking into account the `[IDCliente]` column.

[image]

Comment: I don't quite follow. Can't you sort your table by [NombreCliente] rather than the concatenated column?

Comment: That's right, I can't sort the `[NombreCliente]` column alphabetically but it has to be concatenated to form a single

Comment: @AlexisOlson I just added an example in which I explain in more detail what I want to achieve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Click the dropdown on the [NombreClient] column and choose Sort ascending.

[image: Screenshot]

If you're using this column in a visual, then you have to use the [Sort by Column](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/create-reports/desktop-sort-by-column) functionality.

[image: Sort by Column]

That will then be used as the default sort order:

[image]

Comment: I did it like the example you share with me, but when transferring the custom column to a table, the order is maintained taking into account the column [IDCliente]


.Since you have the data there, can you do the example of displaying the custom column in a table and see how they are ordered?

Comment: I've edited my answer.

Comment: Excellent answer, clear and concise